# How to check if window has resized in GLFW?

Tags: c++, glfw

I' pretty new to GLFW and am creating an application using ImGui. In the application I'm using a function that sets the windows position. However I want this function to only take place when the window has been resized. How could I get a boolean value for whether or not the window has been resized?

PS: I am not talking about the WindowSizeCallback function I am talking about a boolean value I can map to.

Comment: How about using the "WindowSizeCallback function" to set your own boolean flag?

Comment: Do you know any way to do this? I am very new to coding in general tbh.